# Invalid column name 'id' in Django

Tags: python, sql-server, django, django-models

So i'm using Django models in a different way, I have existing tables in MS SQL server and I would like to access them for my application. I've been following some tutorials in pluralsights and also 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/legacy-databases/. I followed the steps accordingly and got my models ready and,when i used 'migrate' command, I got this error

> “AssertionError: A model can't have more than one AutoField.”

So  I looked up SO and got another documentation by Django

> By default, Django gives each model the following field:
>
> id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
>
> This is an auto-incrementing primary key.
>
> If you’d like to specify a custom primary key, just specify
>   primary_key=True on one of your fields. If Django sees you’ve
>   explicitly set Field.primary_key, it won’t add the automatic id
>   column.
>
> Each model requires exactly one field to have primary_key=True (either
>   explicitly declared or automatically added).

So by his solution, i've added 'id' column to the tables which don't have a primary key and skipped the ones which had.
And my 'migrate' command worked smooth.

But When I'm trying to test if i can get values from it, it shows  Invalid column 'ID'

Now, I keep thinking myself, if Django creates them implicitly, or when I create it explicitly inside the models( and then using makemigrations and migrate command), shouldn't it have created the column for it?

Another scenario:
There are some tables with primary key already established, I've tried queries on them and it worked.

This just makes me think if I missed a step inbetween all these,

Here's my  lib files

```
certifi==2016.2.28
Django==1.11.3
django-mssql==1.8
django-pyodbc-azure==1.11.0.0
mysqlclient==1.3.12
PyMySQL==0.7.9
pyodbc==4.0.17
pytz==2017.2
wincertstore==0.2
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, but please help if I had missed any step for connecting with legacy systems.Please do ask if any extra information is needed. Thanks!

Edit: As asked, this is the model where my query worked

```
class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'
```

And here's the one(Of many) that did not work

```
class table1(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    col2 = models.CharField(db_column='col2', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    col3 = models.IntegerField(db_column='col3', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    col4 = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    col5 = models.DateTimeField(db_column='col5')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'table1'
```

The session_key variable has been in the table, hence I did not have the need to create a primary key for that table.
Whereas, the `id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)` has been added by me because of various documentations I've read, I've tried the 'implicitly added' method of creating id too, but it gives the same.

The sql shell query that introduced this error:

```
from app.models import table1
table1.objects.filter(column_name='col3')
```

The migration.createModel function is as belows

```
migrations.CreateModel(
            name='VikalpFtrFeatureCr',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('col2', models.CharField(blank=True, db_column='col2', max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('col3', models.IntegerField(blank=True, db_column='col3', null=True)),
                ('col4', models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250, null=True)),
                ('col5', models.DateTimeField(db_column='UPDATE_DTTM')),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
                'db_table': 'VIKALP_FTR_Feature_CR',
            },
        )
```

Comment: Could you post one of the models that your had before adding the `AutoField`, and the model after you changed it to _"i've added 'id' column to the tables which don't have a primary key"_.

Comment: add `models.py` in your question

Comment: I'll edit the question along with the models, thank you.

Comment: See the difference in the `managed` metaclass property?

Comment: 1.Shouldn't it be true so that django can add the id column to table?
2.Tried managed=False on problem-facing table, still no progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite unclear why you got the initial assertion error. I think you diagnosed it wrongly and took the wrong action. Now we can't tell what really happened and it's difficult to help you further.

I suggest you backup the app's `migrations` folder. Let's call your app "msapp" for the rest of this and substitute it where appropriate.

First, rollback migrations:

```
python manage.py migrate msapp zero
```

Now remove all migration files:

```
rm msapp/migrations/0*.py
```

Then clear models.py:

```
rm msapp/models.py && touch msapp/models.py
```

Run inspectdb using list of wanted tables:

```
python manage.py inspectdb table1 table2 ... >> msapp/models.py
```

Run makemigrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations msapp
```

Run migrate:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Now show what problem you run into and the **full traceback** if you run into the assertion error again.

### Update

So the issue is that Django will add an auto created field to the model when there is no primary key, **even if the model is marked as unmanaged**.
The [consensus](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/R3yv_tmoSGw) seems to be that one can simply pick a field and mark it primary key even if it isn't one. That will prevent the auto-inserted ID field, which is done in the meta class in `django.db.models.options`:

```
def _prepare():
    # ...
    if self.pk is None:
        if self.parents:
            # Promote the first parent link in lieu of adding yet another
            # field.
            field = next(six.itervalues(self.parents))
            # Look for a local field with the same name as the
            # first parent link. If a local field has already been
            # created, use it instead of promoting the parent
            already_created = [fld for fld in self.local_fields if fld.name == field.name]
            if already_created:
                field = already_created[0]
            field.primary_key = True
            self.setup_pk(field)
            if not field.remote_field.parent_link:
                warnings.warn(
                    'Add parent_link=True to %s as an implicit link is '
                    'deprecated.' % field, RemovedInDjango20Warning
                )
        else:
            auto = AutoField(verbose_name='ID', primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
            model.add_to_class('id', auto)
```

Another option is to always use [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#defer) when dealing with those models, so that the 'id' field is never queried from the database. You can test this with your current setup by doing:

```
table1.objects.filter(column_name='col3').defer('id')
```

This you can further abstract in a manager:

```
class NoPkModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(NoPkModelManager, self).get_queryset().defer('id')

class Table1(models.Model):
    objects = NoPkModelManager()
    # .. other fields and methods
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the clear steps, I've tried it out as given by you,
And this is my traceback

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: I could give more information if required, since I'm new to Django, I've read different documentation(for the same django version) and written down the steps I followed.

Comment: This is triggered by the migrate command? Is it also triggered by the "check" command? I do not see any references to migration code, which is what I expect to see. In fact, there's no normal way a traceback could start in db/backends/utils.py. If you ran out of room, update your question instead.

Comment: No, this commented error is from shell from the following command,`table1.objects.filter(column_name='col3')`.
I'm not sure what you mean by migration code, but i'll edit the question to incorporate the migrations.createModel function.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I will accept the answer because of the "consensus" link, because the workaround provided by him well, worked for me too. But i don't know if its the correct one

Comment: but the table1.objects.filter(column_name='col1').defer('id') did not work,Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 65, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\django\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 545, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'id'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")

It still gave the same Error.

Answer (score 1):

Basically to get legacy databases/tables/views working, you need at least one field which is unique across the table/view.

All you need to to is to put the right field type (e.g. CharField, IntegerField - in my example I have used CharField) and put in the Meta options the table name and set managed to False.

```
class YourLegacyModel(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(db_column='unique column', primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'your_table'
        managed = False
```

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly. I've created the primary key column to be unique across the table.
I've put managed = True because I would like to do CRUD operations on it.

Comment: That's not the way. Let managed be false and you are able to do crud operations too.

Comment: `By default, inspectdb creates unmanaged models. That is, managed = False in the model’s Meta class tells Django not to manage each table’s creation, modification, and deletion:`
This is the documentation I was referring to.

Comment: But you don't want to create new tables. I thought you were accessing a legacy database?!

Comment: Yes I am accessing legacy database, and I now understand that Django refers to CRUD of the table and not of the data, I will test it out and get back here, thanks!

Comment: I've made it to False, and then ran makemigrations command, then ran migrate command(here for both it says "No change detected") and then tried to run the query again, it failed with the "invalid column id" error again